# SQL query to find the faculty which have taught every subject

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions, subquery

I need to write a SQL query to find the faculty which has taught every subject (ie Sam)

1. With nested queries
2. Without using aggregate functions (no count, avg, min etc).

I can't seem to figure this out, would really appreciate some help =)

Faculty

| fid | fname | fqualifications | fexperience | salary | deptname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Sam | ME CS | 10 | 100000 | IT |
| 101 | John | ME IT | 8 | 80000 | IT |
| 102 | Max | ME CS | 9 | 90000 | CS |
| 103 | Jenny | ME CS | 5 | 50000 | CS |

Course

| cid | cname | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SE | 4 |
| 2 | WT | 4 |
| 3 | CG | 5 |
| 4 | DBMS | 5 |

Teaches

| fid | cid | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2019 |
| 100 | 2 | 2018 |
| 100 | 3 | 2020 |
| 100 | 4 | 2021 |
| 101 | 1 | 2017 |
| 101 | 2 | 2018 |
| 102 | 2 | 2018 |
| 102 | 3 | 2019 |
| 103 | 3 | 2020 |
| 103 | 4 | 2021 |

I used this query to find the output but according to the question I can't.

```
select * from faculty f
    -> inner join teaches t
    -> on f.fid=t.fid
    -> inner join course c
    -> on t.cid=c.cid
    -> group by f.fid,f.fname
    -> having count(*)=4;
```

OUTPUT:

| fid | fname | fqualifications | fexperience | salary | deptname | fid | cid | year | cid | cname | semester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Sam | ME CS | 10 | 100000 | IT | 100 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | SE | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way to proceed, but with the requirements given to you, I would try and rephrase the query like this:

"A faculty that has taught every subject is a faculty that has **not** skipped even one subject".

Now, faculties that *have* skipped a subject will have a NULL when LEFT JOINed with the syllabus and *all* the subjects. Pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT faculty.id FROM faculties 
    LEFT JOIN has_taught ON (has_taught.faculty_id = faculty.id)
    LEFT JOIN subjects ON (has_taught.subject_id = subjects.id)
    WHERE has_taught.faculty_id IS NULL;
```

or in some databases you maybe need

```
SELECT DISTINCT faculty.id FROM faculties 
    CROSS JOIN subjects
    LEFT JOIN has_taught ON 
      (has_taught.faculty_id = faculty.id AND has_taught.subject_id = subjects.id)
    WHERE has_taught.faculty_id IS NULL;
```

So, faculties that are `NOT IN` this list would naturally be

```
SELECT * FROM faculties
    WHERE faculty.id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT faculty.id ...
    );
```

and this should only use nested queries, as requested.

Or with a further join

```
SELECT faculties.* FROM faculties
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT faculty.id ...
    ) AS they_skipped_some
    ON (they_skipped_some.id = faculties.id)
    WHERE they_skipped_some.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but I'm afriad this isn't what I was looking for.The first part returns the faculty who haven't taught a single subject, the final nested query returns the faculty who don't belong to this list ie(have taught a subject). The issue is I'm looking for faculty who have taught **every** subject, the current query returns all of them.

Comment: Have you tried the `CROSS JOIN` version? I don't see how it could *not* work, seeing as how a CROSS JOIN should return the full cartesian product of both tables.